# list item tap issue - on single click two views gets added

Tags: sencha-touch-2

When I single Tap on list item view gets added twice. Issue is I have to click back button twice to come back on the same page. Anybody knows what is exact issue.
If possible Provide some reference code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I was facing same issue use below code it will fix your issue.

```
if (this.getNavigationView().getActiveItem().xtype != "viewName") {
   this.getNavigationView().push({ xtype: "viewName" });
}
```

Good Luck..